# CSS detect which tab is rendered and change opacity for the active tab dynamically

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

so I have a jsx element that looks like this

```
            </div>
            {mainHeader == 1 && (
              <Profile />
            )}
           {mainHeader == 2 && (
              <Account />
            )}
        {mainHeader == 3 && (
              <Settings />
            )}
          </div>
```

this is some sort of tab, based on which button is selected in the header a different element appears. this might not be the best way to implement tabs, but it works fine.

Anyway.
in my CSS I  have this in the parent div of all those elements

```
.content-wrapper {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear;
```

what I want to achieve is that when I change elements from one another it fade in/out but this is not working any idea how I can achieve that?